# Rvest webscraping limited results (R)

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am new to webscraping and have tried several methods to perform a rvest across multiple pages. Somehow it is still not working and I only get 15 results instead of the 207 products listed in this category. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(rvest)
all_df<-0
library(data.table)

for(i in 1:5){
  url_fonq <- paste0("https://www.fonq.nl/producten/categorie-lichtbronnen/?p=",i,sep="")
  webpage_fonq <- read_html(url_fonq)
  head(webpage_fonq)

  product_title_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage_fonq, '.product-title')
  product_title_data <- html_text(product_title_data_html)
  head(product_title_data)
  product_title_data<-gsub("\n","",product_title_data)
  product_title_data<-gsub(" ","",product_title_data)
  head(product_title_data)
  length(product_title_data)

  product_price_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage_fonq, '.product-price')
  product_price_data <- html_text(product_price_data_html)
  head(product_price_data)
  product_price_data<-gsub("\n","",product_price_data)
  product_price_data<-gsub(" ","",product_price_data)
  head(product_price_data)
  product_price_data
  length(product_price_data)
  fonq.df <- data.frame(Procuct_title = product_title_data, Price = product_price_data)
  all_df <-list(fonq.df)
  }

final2<-rbindlist(all_df,fill = TRUE)

View(final2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you keep only the data scraped from the *last* page of the website, and thus you have the last 15 products stored only.

So instead of *overwriting* the all_df variable in every iteration

```
all_df <- list(fonq.df)
```

append the `fonq.df` dataframe at the end of the `all_df`:

```
all_df <- bind_rows(all_df, fonq.df)
```

Here is my complete solution:

```
library(rvest)
all_df <- list()
library(dplyr)

for(i in 1:5){

  url_fonq <- paste0("https://www.fonq.nl/producten/categorie-lichtbronnen/?p=",i,sep="")
  webpage_fonq <- read_html(url_fonq)
  head(webpage_fonq)

  product_title_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage_fonq, '.product-title')
  product_title_data <- html_text(product_title_data_html)
  head(product_title_data)
  product_title_data<-gsub("\n","",product_title_data)
  product_title_data<-gsub(" ","",product_title_data)
  head(product_title_data)
  length(product_title_data)

  product_price_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage_fonq, '.product-price')
  product_price_data <- html_text(product_price_data_html)
  head(product_price_data)
  product_price_data<-gsub("\n","",product_price_data)
  product_price_data<-gsub(" ","",product_price_data)
  head(product_price_data)
  product_price_data
  length(product_price_data)
  fonq.df <- data.frame(Procuct_title = product_title_data, Price = product_price_data)
  all_df <-bind_rows(all_df, fonq.df)
}

View(all_df)
```