# Online newspaper data scraping with R, 'rvest' package

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

My assignment for a course was to scrape data from news media and analyse it.
It is my first experience of scraping with R and I got stuck for several weeks with obtaining the data, checking various guides, all of which end up with a limited output or an error.

First of all, I tried a guide from [Analyticsvidhya](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/03/beginners-guide-on-web-scraping-in-r-using-rvest-with-hands-on-knowledge/#h2_2) and this is the clearest code that I have obtained. I started with scraping only one page from the newspaper's archive:

```
library('rvest')
library('xml2')
library(dplyr)

url <- 'https://en.trend.az/archive/2021-11-03'
library("rvest")
html <- read_html(url)
headline_html <- html_nodes(html,'.category-article .article-title')
#144 articles according by (c)SelectorGadget
headline <- html_text(headline_html)
#print(headline)
length(headline)
```

I have tried similar codes for other CSS selectors, but I could not obtain more than 9 results.

I considered that the problem may be with the URL, so decided to scrape from a set of subpages covering several days in the archive.

This is a code according to [an answer in the StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52296018/rvest-webscraping-limited-results-r)

```
all_df <- list()
arch_date <- seq(as.Date("2021-11-03"), as.Date("2021-11-13"), by="days")

for(i in 'rchdate'){

  url_fonq <- str_c ('https://en.trend.az', "/archive/", arch_date)
  webpage_fonq <- read_html(url_fonq)
  head(webpage_fonq)

  headline_html <- html_nodes(webpage_fonq,'.category-article .article-title')
  headline <- html_text(headline_html)
  head(headline)
  headline <- str_trim(headline)
  head(headline)
  length(headline)
```

... (omit here similar commands for other nodes)

```
  fonq.df <- data.frame( Num = row_number,
                    Date = date,
                    Time = time,
                    Title = headline,
                    Category = cat)

  all_df <-bind_rows(all_df, fonq.df)
}
```

and this is an error that I could not fix:

> Error: `x` must be a string of length 1
> 7. stop("`x` must be a string of length 1", call. = FALSE)
> 6. read_xml.character(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE,  options = options)
> 5. read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE, options = options)
> 4. withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = function(w) if (inherits(w,  classes)) tryInvokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
> 3. suppressWarnings(read_xml(x, encoding = encoding, ..., as_html = TRUE,  options = options))
> 2. read_html.default(url_fonq)
>
> 1. read_html(url_fonq)

Before I tried a more detailed but ambiguous guide for beginners from [the DataCamp](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/r-web-scraping-rvest), which did end up with an unresolved error.

```
url <- 'https://en.trend.az/archive/2021-11-03'
headline_html <- read_html(url)  

get_headline <- function(html){
      html %>% 
        # The relevant tag
        html_nodes('.category-article .article-title') %>%       
        html_text() %>%   
        # Trim additional white space - important function
        str_trim() %>%                        
        # Convert the list into a vector
        unlist()                             
}
```

... (omit here similar commands for other nodes)

```
get_data_table <- function(html, company_name){
        headline <- get_headline(html)
        time <- get_time(html)
        
        combine_data <- tibble(Abstract = headline,
                               Date = time
                               )
        combined_data %>%
          mutate(Trend.AZ = company_name) %>% 
        select(Trend.AZ, Abstract, Date)
}

get_data_from_url <- function(url, company_name){
      html <- read_html(url)
      get_data_table(html, company_name)
}

scrape_write_table <- function(url, company_name){
  
      url <- "https://en.trend.az"
      arch_date <- seq(as.Date("2021-10-01"), as.Date("2021-11-01"), by="days")
      list_of_url <- str_c (url, "/archive/", arch_date)  

      list_of_url %>% 
        map(get_data_from_url, company_name) %>%  
        bind_rows() %>% 
        write_tsv(str_c(company_name,'.tsv'))     
}

scrape_write_table(url, 'Trend.AZ') 
# !!!The error was after here!!!

trend_az_tbl <- read_tsv('Trend.AZ')
    tail(amz_tbl, 11)
```

The error:

> Error in html_elements(...) : object '*tmp*' not found
> 15. html_elements(...)
> 14. html_nodes(., ".category-article .article-date")
> 13. `*tmp*` %>% html_nodes(".category-article .article-date")
> 12. get_time(html)
> 11. get_data_table(html, company_name)
> 10. .f(.x[[i]], ...)
> 9. map(., get_data_from_url, company_name)
> 8. list2(...)
> 7. bind_rows(.)
> 6. is.data.frame(x)
> 5. stopifnot(is.data.frame(x))
> 4. write_delim(x, file, delim = "\t", na = na, append = append,  col_names = col_names, quote = quote, escape = escape, eol = eol,
> num_threads = num_threads, progress = progress)
> 3. write_tsv(., str_c(company_name, ".tsv"))
> 2. list_of_url %>% map(get_data_from_url, company_name) %>% bind_rows() %>%  write_tsv(str_c(company_name, ".tsv"))
>
> 1. scrape_write_table(url, "Trend.AZ")

I would be extremely thankful for any comment or suggestions regarding any of these 3 codes.
I am really in a hurry to move to the analysis part of the project to be able to generate a report by the end of the course.

Comment: Do you want to get only article title?

Comment: You didn't specify what you would like to scrape.

Comment: @NadPat I scraped all information available: title, date and time, category, using different CSS selectors for each, but every time I use function `print(headline)` or `print(time)`, the maximum amount of results I get is [9]. May it be just a limitation of the terminal window and in fact, I scrape the whole page?

Comment: @Bloxx All information available per each news (title, date, time, category) during one month. I left only examples of `headline` by the means of space. The idea is to apply pattern analysis later and plot by time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webpage is dynamically loaded, new articles are loaded as you scroll down. Thus you need `RSelenium` and `rvest` to extract required data.

### Launch browser

```
library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)
url = 'https://en.trend.az/archive/2021-11-02'
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$navigate(url)
#click outside in an empty space
remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[1]/h1')$clickElement()

webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")
#scrolling to the end of webpage, to load all articles 
for (i in 1:17){
  Sys.sleep(2)
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
}
```

### Get Article Titles

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>%
html_nodes('.category-article') %>% html_nodes('.article-title') %>% 
  html_text()
[1] "Chelsea defeats Malmö with minimum score"                                                                                                 
 [2] "Iran’s import of COVID-19 vaccine exceeds 146mn doses: IRICA"                                                                             
 [3] "Sadyr Zhaparov, Fumio Kishida discuss topical issues of Kyrgyz-Japanese relations"                                                        
 [4] "We will definitely see new names at World Championships and World Age Group Competitions in Trampoline Gymnastics in Baku - Farid Gayibov"
 [5] "Declaration on forest protection, land use adopted by 105 countries"                                                                      
 [6] "Russian Security Council's chief, CIA director meet in Moscow"                                                                            
 [7] "Israel to exhibit for 1st time at Dubai Airshow"                                                                                          
 [8] "Azerbaijan's General Prosecutor's Office continues to take measures on appeal against Armenia"                                            
 [9] "Azerbaijani, Russian FMs discuss activity of working group for restoration of communications in South Caucasus"                           
[10] "Russia holds tenth meeting of joint Azerbaijani-Russian Demarcation Commission"                                                           
[11] "Only external reasons cause inflation in Azerbaijan - Gazprombank"                                                                        
[12] "State Oil Fund of Azerbaijan launches tender for technical vendor support"
```

### Get Links of articles

```
lin = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>% html_nodes('.category-news-wrapper') %>% html_nodes('.article-link')
```

### Get Article category, date and time

```
remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
  read_html() %>%  
  html_nodes('.category-article') %>% html_nodes('.article-meta') %>% 
  html_text()
 [1] "\n                Other News\n                2 November 23:55\n            "
 [2] "\n                Society\n                2 November 23:14\n            "   
 [3] "\n                Kyrgyzstan\n                2 November 22:55\n            "
 [4] "\n                Society\n                2 November 22:51\n            "   
 [5] "\n                Other News\n                2 November 22:26\n            "
 [6] "\n                Russia\n                2 November 21:50\n            "    
 [7] "\n                Israel\n                2 November 21:24\n            "    
 [8] "\n                Politics\n                2 November 20:50\n            "  
 [9] "\n                Politics\n                2 November 20:25\n            "  
[10] "\n                Politics\n                2 November 20:16\n            "
```

Comment: Sorry for the late update, but your response was very helpful. It did not work in the beginning as long as I did not downgrade Firefox (Version 93.0 (64-bit)). Also combined scraped data another way as I did not get the selector '.category-article .article-meta'
`all_df <- list()
trend_az.df <- data.frame( Number = c(get_number),
                    Date = c(get_date),
                    Time = c(get_time),
                    Category = c(get_cat),
                    Title = c(get_headline),
                    Link = c(get_links))
  all_df <- list(trend_az.df)
print(trend_az.df)`