# Obtaining data from NCBI gene database with R

Tags: html, r, rselenium, ncbi, rentrez

#### Rentrez package

I was discovering `rentrez` package in RStudio (Version 1.1.442) on a lab computer in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.2) according to [this manual](https://bioconnector.github.io/workshops/r-ncbi.html#entrez_search()).
However, later when I wanted to run the same code on my laptop in Windows 8 Pro (RStudio 2021.09.0 )

```
library (rentrez)
entrez_dbs()
entrez_db_searchable("gene")
#res <- entrez_search (db = "gene", term = "(Vibrio[Organism] OR vibrio[All Fields]) AND (16s[All Fields]) AND (rna[All Fields]) AND (owensii[All Fields] OR navarrensis[All Fields])", retmax = 500, use_history = TRUE)
```

I can not get rid of this error, even after closing the session or reinstalling `rentrez` package

> Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) :    schannel:
> next InitializeSecurityContext failed: SEC_E_ILLEGAL_MESSAGE
> (0x80090326) - This error usually occurs when a fatal SSL/TLS alert is
> received (e.g. handshake failed).

This is the main problem that I faced.

#### RSelenium package

Later I decided to address pages containing details about the [genes](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/57838769) and their [sequences in FASTA format](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_ADAF01000001.1?report=fasta&from=257558&to=260444) modifying a code that I have previously used. It uses `rvest` and `rselenium` packages and the results were perfect.

```
# Specifying a webpage

url <- "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/66940694"    # the last 9 numbers is gene id

library(rvest)
library(RSelenium)

# Opening a browser

driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
remDr$errorDetails
remDr$navigate(url)

# Clicked outside in an empty space next to the FASTA button and copied a full xPath (redirecting to a FASTA data containing webpage)

remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/p/a[2]')$clickElement()

webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")

#scrolling to the end of a webpage: left it from the old code for the case of a long gene

for (i in 1:5){
  Sys.sleep(2)
  webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))

# Let's get gene FASTA, for example

page <- read_html(remDr$getPageSource()[[1]])
fasta <- page %>%
html_nodes('pre') %>%
  html_text()
print(fasta)
```

> Output: ">NZ_QKKR01000022.1:c3037-151 Vibrio paracholerae strain
> 2016V-1111 2016V-1111_ori_contig_18, whole genome shotgun
> sequence\nGGT...

The code worked well to obtain other details about the gene like its accession number, position, organism and etc.

#### Looping of the process for several gene IDs

Later I tried to change the code to get simultaneously the same information for several gene IDs following [the explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70253842/scraping-several-webpages-from-a-website-newspaper-archive-using-rselenium) I got here for the other project of mine.

```
# Specifying a list of gene IDs

res_id <- c('57838769','61919208','66940694')
dt <- res_id    # <lapply> looping function refused to work if an argument had a different name rather than <dt>
  
driver <- rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))  
remDr <- driver[["client"]]

## Writing a function of GET_FASTA dependent on GENE_ID (x)

get_fasta <- function(x){
  link = paste0('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/',x)
  remDr$navigate(link)
  remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/p/a[2]')$clickElement()
```

... there is a continuation below but an error was appearing here, saying that the same xPath, which was successfully used before, can not be found.

> Error: Summary: NoSuchElement Detail: An element could not be located
> on the page using the given search parameters. class:
> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException Further Details: run
> errorDetails method

I tried to delete `/a[2]` to get `/html/.../p` at the end of the xPath as it was working in the initial code, but an error was appearing later again.

```
  webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")

  for (i in 1:5){
    Sys.sleep(2)
    webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
  } 

 # Addressing selectors of FASTA on the website
  
  fasta <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('pre') %>%
    html_text()
  fasta
  return(fasta)
}

## Writing a function of GET_ACC_NUM dependent on GENE_ID (x)

get_acc_num <- function(x){
  link = paste0( 'https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/', x)
  remDr$navigate(link)
  remDr$findElement(using = "xpath", value = '/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/form/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[6]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/p')$clickElement()
  webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "body")

  for (i in 1:5){
    Sys.sleep(2)
    webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end"))
  } 
  
  # Addressing selectors of ACC_NUM on the website
  
  acc_num <- remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('.itemid') %>%
    html_text() %>%
    str_sub(start= -17)
  acc_num
  return(acc_num)
}

## Collecting all FUNCTION into tibble

get_data_table <- function(x){

      # Extract the Basic information from the HTML
      fasta <- get_fasta(x)
      acc_num <- get_acc_num(x)

      # Combine into a tibble
      combined_data <- tibble( Acc_Number = acc_num,
                               FASTA = fasta)
}

## Running FUNCTION for all x

df <- lapply(dt, get_data_table)

head(df)
```

I also tried to write the code

- only with `rvest`,
- to write the loop with `for (i in res_id) {}`,
- to introduce two different xPaths ending with `/html/.../p/a[2]` or `.../p` using `if () {} else {}`

but the results were even more confusing.

I am studying R coding while working on such tasks, so any suggestions and critics are welcome.

Comment: `fasta` is returning empty. And it should be `.pre` not `pre` if such a node were to exist. Can you provide the output of `fasta` that you tried for single gene. And error w.r.t. `rentrez`  package i saw many people asking similar question maybe can find a solution there? Include a `r` tag so that you can reach more people.

Comment: @NadPat You are right. The full xPath should be `/html/.../p/a[2]`, otherwise, fasta is empty. Have corrected the question above.  I checked fasta selector and it is `pre`, without a dot. Check here: (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_ADAF01000001.1?report=fasta&from=257558&to=260444) The output for a code with one gene id is the next: [1] ">NZ_ADAF01000001.1:257558-260444 Vibrio mimicus MB451 strain MB-451 Contig43, whole genome shotgun sequence\nGGT...\nCCGTGAGGCTTAACCAT\n\n" I experimented later with the xPath when it said that there is no such element.

Comment: @NadPat I have checked the explanation for curl error, not connected with `rentrez` package. But they were beyond me. Generally, 'rentrez` was specifically made for getting information from NCBI databases, initially in Python.  But using the selectors directly makes work shorter excluding a step with regular expressions in a set of files in .gb format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node `pre` is not a valid one. We have to look for value inside `class` or 'id` etc.

`webElem$sendKeysToElement(list(key = "end")` you don't need this command as there is no necessity yo scroll the page.

Below is code to get you the sequence of genes.

**First we have to get the links to sequence of genes which we do it by `rvest`**

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
res_id <- c('57838769','61919208','66940694')

link = vector()
for(i in res_id){
  url = paste0('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/', i)
  df = url %>%
    read_html() %>% 
    html_node('.note-link') 
  
  link1 = xml_attrs(xml_child(df, 3))[["href"]]
  link1 = paste0('https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov', link1)
  link = rbind(link, link1)
}

link1 "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_ADAF01000001.1?report=fasta&from=257558&to=260444"       
link1 "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_VARQ01000103.1?report=fasta&from=64&to=2616&strand=true" 
link1 "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore/NZ_QKKR01000022.1?report=fasta&from=151&to=3037&strand=true"
```

After obtaining the links we shall get the sequence of genes which we do it by `RSelenium`. I tried to do it with `rvest` but couldn't get the sequence.

**Launch browser**

```
library(RSelenium)
driver = rsDriver(browser = c("firefox"))
remDr <- driver[["client"]]
```

**Function to get the sequence**

```
get_seq = function(link){
  remDr$navigate(link)
  Sys.sleep(5)
  df = remDr$getPageSource()[[1]] %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="viewercontent1"]') %>% 
    html_text()
  return(df)
}

df = lapply(link, get_seq)
```

Now we have list `df` with all the info.

Comment: The code works perfectly with some adjustments that we needed, considering the aims of our work.The code was giving an error in the beginning until I installed ´xml2´ package.
Regarding the `rentrez` package, it started to work after we updated Ubuntu on our computer, so the reasons of the previous error stay mysterious.